# how to scale down instances based on their uptime with apache marathon?

Tags: mesos, marathon, mesosphere, dcos

I find myself in a situation where I have the necessity to scale down container instances based on their actual lifetime. It looks like fresh instances are removed first when scaling down through marathon's API. **Is there any configuration I'm not aware of to implement this kind of strategy or policy when scaling down instances on apache marathon?**

As of right now I'm using [marathon-lb-autoscale](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-lb-autoscale) to atumatically adjust the number of running instances. What actually happens under the hood though is that `marathon-lb-autoscale` does perform a `PUT` request updating the `instances` property of the current application when req/s increases or decreaseas.

```
scale_list.each do |app,instances|
    req = Net::HTTP::Put.new('/v2/apps/' + app)
    if !@options.marathonCredentials.empty?
      req.basic_auth(@options.marathonCredentials[0], @options.marathonCredentials[1])
    end
    req.content_type = 'application/json'
    req.body = JSON.generate({'instances'=>instances})
    Net::HTTP.new(@options.marathon.host, @options.marathon.port).start do |http|
      http.request(req)
    end
  end
end
```

I don't know if the [`upgradeStrategy`](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/rest-api.html#-upgradestrategy) configuration is taken into account when scaling down instances. With default settings i cannot get the expected behaviour to work.

```
{
  "upgradeStrategy": {
    "minimumHealthCapacity": 1,
    "maximumOverCapacity": 1
  }
}
```

#### ACTUAL

- instance 1
- instance 2
- `PUT /v2/apps/my-app {instances: 3}`
- instance 1
- instance 2
- instance 3
- `PUT /v2/apps/my-app {instances: 2}`
- instance 1
- instance 2

#### EXPECTED

- instance 1
- instance 2
- `PUT /v2/apps/my-app {instances: 3}`
- instance 1
- instance 2
- instance 3
- `PUT /v2/apps/my-app {instances: 2}`
- instance 2
- instance 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can specify a `killSelection` directly inside the application's config and specify `YoungestFirst` which kills youngest tasks first or `OldestFirst` which kills the oldest ones first.

Reference: https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/configure-task-handling.html